# Relation of the length of latus rectum with the distance between focus and vertex and distance to focus from directix

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

In this [website](https://socratic.org/questions/what-is-the-length-of-the-latus-rectum-of-the-parabola-whose-focus-is-1-1-and-di#:%7E:text=Length%20of%20latus%20rectum%20is%20twice%20the%20distance%20between%20focus,distance%20of%20focus%20from%20directrix.&text=Hence%2C%20length%20of%20latus%20rectum%20is%2010%20.), the following statement is written

> Length of latus rectum is twice the distance between focus and vertex or four times the distance of focus from the directrix.

I thought of proving the statement for a parabola whose focus lies on the $y$ axis and this would prove the geometric idea for all other parabolas since all other are just shifted/stretched variations of the one in consideration. The proof is presented in the following section.

---

Set of points equidistance from line and point. For a parabole opening up like a U in the x-y plane, say it is parallel its line is $y=c$ and the point is $(a,b)$ then the distance from these two are the same.

$$ (y-c)^2 = (x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 \tag{1}$$

Now, the for the points which are same vertical height as directrix, plug  $y=b$,

$$ a \pm (b-c) = x$$

Hence the distance between the two points:

$$ l= 2 (b-c)$$

"The length of latus rectum is twice the perpendicular distance between directrix and focus"

But the statement says that it is four times, so is it wrong or did I make mistake?

---

For the second part, we can find the maxima of $y$ is when $x=a$ by differentiation and hence,

$$ y-c = -(y-b)$$

$$ 2y = b-c$$

Hence, the vertex is given as:

$$ y = \frac{b-c}{2}$$

Now since focus at (a,b) the distance between vertex and focus :

$$ d = \frac{b+c}{2}$$

Which doesn't even seem to be related to original equation

Comment: The statement asserts that $$2\times(\text{focus-to-vertex}) = 4\times(\text{focus-to-directrix})$$ which cannot be true, as the vertex lies between the focus and directrix. So, the author inadvertently swapped "directrix" and "vertex" (or "twice" and "four times"); these things happen. Note that in the working of the problem, the author correctly *calculated* the latus rectum by merely *doubling* the focus-to-directrix distance.

Comment: Oh nice,  is my proof correct by the way?

Answer (score 1):

For the parabola $y^2=4ax$, the equation of Latus rectum is $x=a$ and end points of Lr are $(a,2a)$ and $(a,-2a)$ so $Lr=4a$. The vertex is $V(0,0)$ directrix is $x=-a$
The point of intersection of directrix and x-axis is $Z(-a,0)$ so $VZ=a$. Focus is $F(a,0)$ so $VF=a$. So finally $VF=VZ=Lr/4.$